Compatibility of Different ROS 2 Distributions and DDS Implementations
We are using ROS 2 for our projects and robots and work with teams of ROS 2 robots which communicate over the network. However, we are finding it difficult to synchronize ROS 2 distributions or DDS versions across all platforms.

Is there an official statement about the compatibility of different ROS 2 distributions?
Is there an official statement about the compatibility of different DDS Implementations?
What have been your experiences and challenges in managing compatibility between different ROS 2 distributions and DDS implementations?

Looking forward to your insights and experiences.
Thanks in advance!

As discussed here on ROSAnsweres this is not ensured or recommended. It might work but I suggest to check the release notes for every used distribution (maybe more work than acutally installing the same distro everywhere).
Perhaps it is not necessary to synchronise at all, but it is sufficient to install the same distribution once everywhere. Or should the distribution be changed over time?
